# Converting list to string?

Tags: python

In order to use `random.choice()`, I have to convert my string to a list:

```
>>> x = "hello"
>>> y = list(x)
>>> y
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

But trying to do that in reverse yields a string that actually looks like `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']` instead of just `hello`. Doing this repeatedly causes an infinite loop that produces strings which look like this:

```
"'", '"', ',', ' ', "'", ',', "'", ',', ' ', "'", ' ', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '"', "'", ',', ' ', '"', "'", '"', ',', ' ', "'", '"', "'", ',', ' ', "'", ',', "'", ',', ' ', "'", ' ', "'", ',', ' ', '"', "'", '"', ',', ' ', "'", ',', "'", ',', ' ', '"', "'", '"', ',', ' ', "'", ',', "'", ',', ' ', "'", ' ', "'", ',', ' '
```

And so on.

So, how can I convert the list back into a string:

```
>>> x = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> y = something(x)
>>> y
'xyz'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> x = "hello"
>>> y = list(x)
>>> y
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> ''.join(y)
'hello'
```

Answer (score 7):

`"".join (x)` will do it quite easily.

Answer (score 4):

To convert a list to a string in python like you want, you can use the `string.join` operator.

```
 >>> x = ['x', 'y', 'z']
 >>> y = "".join(x)
 >>> y
 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 4):

Python String [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) does the trick.

```
>>> ''.join(y)
'xyz'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = 'abc'
>>> y = list(x)
>>> y
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ''.join(y)
'abc'
>>>
```

And to use `random.choice`, there is no need for you to parse the string to list, the string itself is a sequence:

```
>>> random.choice('abc')
'c'
>>> random.choice('abc')
'a'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

While several of these answers correctly answer the question of converting a list to a string, I would note that your actual problem is that you want to use random.choice() on a string and want to convert it to a list first. You don't need to do that -- random.choice() takes any sequence, including a string.

```
x = 'abcde'
y = [random.choice(x) for i in range(5)]
print y
```

Comment: That would be easier, but I need `list`'s `insert`, `remove`, `index`, etc, and string --> list --> string winds up being worth the extra step in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use join:

```
>>> li=['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> print ''.join(li)
```

ie, that reverses what applying the list constructor does to a string:

```
>>> ''.join(list('hello'))
'hello'
```

Comment: May I ask why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't do the downvote, but I notice that @MattBryant also has a downvote and your two posts are the only two that define the list directly instead of generating them from a string...  Maybe somebody *really* doesn't like creating lists of characters directly?